# Graph theory name for minimum depth to leaf node.

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

In a graph theory rooted tree, is there a name for the minimum depth downwards to reach a leaf node?

I have in mind calculating "depth to a leaf" at each node by looking downwards through the subtree starting there.  If the node is a leaf itself then result=0, otherwise if one of its children is a leaf then result=1, otherwise if one of its grandchilden is a leaf then result=2, etc.  For a "complete" tree with no leaf at all then, umm, result undefined or infinite or something.

Comment: Nope$^*$! You can name it. (The maximum distance to a leaf would be the eccentricity of the root.)
*: Obvious caveats apply

Comment: I thought perhaps "leaf distance" for the nearest leaf by any path or "leaf distance down" in the subtree.  If I have instead any DAG is there a name for distance to the nearest terminal node?